# Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template: Illegal characters in path

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

when I[image] am installing react npx create-react-app such errors occur

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
npm cache clear --force
```

then

```
npx create-react-app mehreen_practice
```